# redis-client implementation issue

Tags: node.js, redis

i'm trying to implement a simple redis-client to interact with redis-server.so i have I have written two class like this:

```
    class x {
    write(cmd) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            socket.write(getBuffer(cmd))
            socket.on("data", data => resolve(data.toString("utf-8")))
        })
    }
}
class f extends x {
    constructor() { super() }
    get(data) {
        return this.write(data)
    }
    set(data) {
        return this.write(data)
    }
}
```

and then i'm calling get and set method like this:

```
const red = new f()
red.get([data])
red.set([data])
```

so imagine this two method should return something like this

```
red.get()//should return "cup"
and then 
red.set()//should return "ok"
```

so when i'm calling these method in sequence always result of two method returns in each method like this:

```
red.get([data])// returns "cup \r\n ok"
red.set([data])// returns "cup \r\n ok"
```

how can i solve this bug guys.I want each method to return its result as follows:

```
red.get([data])// returns "cup"
red.set([data])// returns "ok"
```

Comment: Why would you need to create your own Redis client for node? There are already quite a few: https://redis.io/clients#nodejs

Comment: i'm trying to get deep understand in redis and node.js and for that i'm implementing stuffs like this. so how can i solve this issue :)) ?
@Anton